# Compositions of function proof

Tags: calculus

How prove that there is a finite set of functions whose compositions can express any function from a given sequence?

UPD
this is an infinite sequence of functions on R, g1, g2, ..., g_n, ..., it is necessary to prove that there exists a finite set of functions f1, f2, ... f_N such that any function g can be written as compositions these functions

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense.  What does "from a given sequence" mean?  Suppose you have a function $f$, defined however.  Then $f$ is a composition of itself with the identity function.  And this proves the claim.

Comment: What do you mean by *from a given sequence*? You need to be more specific. Do you have a particular sequence of functions, and you want to prove that there is a finite set of functions whose compositions generate any term of this sequence? If so, then specify the sequence; otherwise I simply don't see how to do this in general for an arbitrary sequence of functions.

Comment: Yes, this is an infinite sequence of functions on R, g1, g2, ..., gn, ..., it is necessary to prove that there exists a finite set of functions f1, f2, ... f_N such that any function g can be written as compositions these functions

Answer (score 0):

$f_0(x)=0$ and $f_1(x)=x+1$. We can just define $f_2$ on intervals (0;1), (1;2), ...  with use of arctan function and g1, g2,... and some other functions, so their domain is compressed from R to interval. Finally, $f_3$ is a tan function.