# Series of real function as composition of finite set of functions!

Tags: real-analysis

I was amazed by this problem:

Assume we have countably infinite set of functions $g_1, g_2, ...$. Each of them maps from real numbers to real numbers.

Then somehow there is a finite set of functions $f_1,...,f_n$ such that each $g_k$ is a composition of these functions.

Is it true?
How one can prove it?
Maybe there is some example?

My trivial example: if every function $g_k$ is some positive integer constant, then $f_0(x)=0$ and $f_1(x)=x+1$.

I tried to reformulate the question   that was previously asked here: [Compositions of function proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353280/compositions-of-function-proof)

Maybe $g:N\to (R\to R)$ transformed to $q:R\to (N\to R)$ will help somehow?

Answer (score 1):

We can just define $f_2$ on intervals (0;1), (1;2), ...  with use of arctan function and g1, g2,... and some other functions, so their domain is compressed from R to interval. Finally, $f_3$ is a tan function . The other functions I already wrote in my question.